# Connecting online database with my laravel project

Tags: database, laravel-5

I bulit the website using laravel 5.4 and, I have uploaded it my website on a shared hosting (aruba.it), now I am facing an issue which  I believe in my database connection(connect the database with the laravel project in .env file ) and i get the following error

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `galleries`)
```

My .env file is

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:/9SmuKSXz43JnO3QZP9rv2jp91xTuVornyzBvsRZDuE=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://www.petronius1926.com/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST= myhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Thank you in advance for the help 
PS I checked a lot of old posts and i couldn't find a solution

Comment: Are both database and laravel in the same machine?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database remotely? Be sure that the connection to the port (3306) is allowed by the firewall of both hosting and the os.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov,  yes both of them in the same machine, yes I made sure that the connection is allowed, but still no luck , thank you

Comment: Try `php artisan config:clear` then `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

In you env file you have:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST= myhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

These are the default values.  As you mentioned the database server is on the same machine as the web server the DB_HOST value should be *localhost* or *127.0.0.1*

You would also have to change the user name and password and the db name to match the database user and database on your mysql server.

After that as  Orkhan Alikhanov mentioned you would have to run:

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan config:cache
```

In the root directory of your Laravel project.